# Filter nested array using jmes query

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have to get the name of companies in which 'John' worked in the 'sales' department. My JSON
looks like this:

```json
[
            {
            "name" : "John",
            "company" : [{
                        "name" : "company1",
                        "department" : "sales"
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "company2",
                        "department" : "backend"
                        },
                        {
                        "name" : "company3",
                        "department" : "sales"
                        }
                      ],
            "phone" : "1234"
            }
]
```

And my jmesquery is like this:

```
jmesquery: "[? name=='John'].company[? department=='sales'].{Company: name}"
```

But with this query, I'm getting a `null` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your first filter `[?name=='John']` is creating a [projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#projections), and more specifically a [filter projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections), that you will have to reset in order to further filter it.
Resetting a projection can be achieved using [pipes](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#pipes).

> Projections are an important concept in JMESPath. However, there are times when projection semantics are not what you want. A common scenario is when you want to operate of the result of a projection rather than projecting an expression onto each element in the array.
> For example, the expression `people[*].first` will give you an array containing the first names of everyone in the people array. What if you wanted the first element in that list? If you tried `people[*].first[0]` that you just evaluate `first[0]` for each element in the people array, and because indexing is not defined for strings, the final result would be an empty array, `[]`. To accomplish the desired result, you can use a pipe expression, `<expression> | <expression>`, to indicate that a projection must stop.

<sup>*Source: https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions*</sup>

So, here would be a first step in your query:

```
[?name=='John'] | [].company[?department=='sales'].{Company: name}
```

---

This said, this still ends in an array of array:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "Company": "company1"
    },
    {
      "Company": "company3"
    }
  ]
]
```

Because you can end up with multiple people named `John` in a `sales department`.
So, one array for the `users` and another for the `companies/departments`.

In order to fix this, you can use the [flatten operator](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator): `[]`.

So we end with:

```
[?name=='John'] | [].company[?department=='sales'].{Company: name} []
```

Which gives:

```json
[
  {
    "Company": "company1"
  },
  {
    "Company": "company3"
  }
]
```

Comment: that was an awesome explanation :)